# How to create input text fields with custom caret and text behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently, I visited a wallpaper sharing website **[wallbase](http://wallbase.cc/)**. The first thing I noticed was the search box. The text input box has a nice css gradient styling. But more interesting is the behavior of its text input caret. It is a white, bright, shiny one. Also the behavior of input text is also customized.

I don't know how it is achieved, and I think it may be possible with CSS along with JavaScript. Can somebody explain the way it is achieved? I am attaching a screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Either buttloads of JS to mimic a normal input but style everything, or a absolutely-positioned `div` covering the OS caret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this plugin could help you [Fancy Input – JQuery Plugin](http://dropthebit.com/580/fancy-input-jquery-plugin/)

```
<!-- ...previous page content... -->
<div>
 <input type='text' >
</div>
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<!-- ...some more content (hopefully)... -->
<script>
 $('div :input').fancyInput();
</script>
```

> "Call the .fancyInput() function on all parents of inputs. With this example code, make sure every input is wrapped in a div."

Answer (score 0):

you can do all with css, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/4QFpg/
the crossborwser gradient can you doit here:
 http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
take a look to the properties border, background and border radius

good luck
pd in the css take a look to the properties or class for a imput

```
input[type="text"], select, textarea, .custom-text-form input[type="email"],    input[type="search"], input[type="password"] {
```

background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #D6D1CA 0%, #FFFFFF 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
     }